# sf::Drawable and sf::Transformable array containing sprites, text and shapes

Tags: c++, types, sfml

I want to create an array that will contain all the sprites, text and shapes that will be drawn onto the window and my question is how can I make this array both sf::Drawable and sf::Transformable?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910297/inheriting-from-transformable-and-drawable-in-sfml?rq=1

Comment: While not a solution for your coding problem, you may want to take a look at Entity systems (EntityX for example) . Those solve the problems you get when you use inheritance for this problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a class inheriting both `Drawable` and `Transformable`. Then you would be able to create an array of that class.

```
class Obj : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
    // class code
}

// somewhere in code...
std::array<Obj, ARRAY_SIZE> arr;
```

Make sure you correctly implement `Drawable` and `Transformable`.

---

Here is a link to the official documentation.

[Transformable](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php) &
[Drawable](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Drawable.php)

---

One way to implement these classes would be something along the lines of:

```
class Obj : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
    public:

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Texture texture;

    // implement sf::Drawable
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        target.draw(sprite, states); // draw sprite
    }

    // implement sf::Transformable
    virtual void SetPosition(const MyVector& v) const
    {
        sprite.setPosition(v.x(), v.y());
    }
}
```

And then in your code you can directly draw and transform the class.

```
// somewhere in code
// arr = std::array<Obj, ARRAY_SIZE>
for (auto s : arr) {
    window.draw(s);
}
```